# Where does flask store token for password recovery?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I need to provide password recovery token in order to test it's functionality with integration test. But I can't trace the place its stored.

Comment: I would expect it in database - but it may depends what you have in `flask`/`flask-security` configration. Did you check what tables you have in databases? Use any database editor/viewer like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) to check what you have in database.

Comment: Sure. I've checked all the tables. Especially user table. It's not there.

Comment: then you have to dig in source code and search how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't. [It hashes the user's current password [hash] and their id](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/3e15d06ee82a728d5cc53059fb28406c7bc6e7aa/flask_security/recoverable.py#L55) and sends that as token. Which is entirely reasonable, since that's already user-specific information stored in the database, no need to generate yet another token. And it will even invalidate itself once the password has been changed. I'd probably add a timestamp somewhere in there though so the link isn't valid forever.

Comment: But flask needs to store some state anyway. In order to know who tries to recover the pass and links validity itself. I would like to set this state, and use the same link each and every time for testing.

Comment: The sent token contains the user id (= who) and the hashed password confirms the validity…!